# Check for datetime in 12 hours to 24 hours Python

Tags: python, json, datetime

I have a JSON file with entries like the following, Now I have 3 specific time periods like `shiftA : 6:00 AM - 2:00 PM shiftB : 2:00 PM - 8:00 PM shiftC : 8:00 PM - 6:00 AM`

```
{
    "time": "2021-01-29 09:50:00",
    "production_A": true,
    "production_B": false
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-01-29 10:10:00",
    "production_A": true,
    "production_B": true
  },
```

How can I convert each shift timing to a variable to be cross-checked with the given JSON time stamp? I am trying to design a Flask API to do this. This is the basic script because I have only started with flask and python.

This is my code so far.

```
import json,datetime
countA = 0
countB = 0
t1 = "2021-01-28T01:30:00Z"
t2 = "2021-01-29T03:30:00Z"
shiftAStart = 
shiftAStop =
shiftBStart = 
shiftBStop = 
shiftCStart = 
shiftCStop = 

t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
with open('sample.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        #time = item.get('time')
        time = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(item.get('time'))
        #timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        #time = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(time)
        if time > t1 and time < t2:
            if item.get('production_A') == True:
                countA += 1
            if item.get('production_B') == True:
                countB += 1

print(countA,countB)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Load the data**

`shifts` and `productions` can be loaded from a file (instead of hard-coded as in below). The format of `shifts` could be as it is defined below (you can use `json.dumps` to get the object into a JSON file). The `with` block should *only* contain the code needed to load the file:

```
with open('sample.json') as f:
    productions = json.load(f)
```

**get_matching_prods function explanation:**

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get a list of the matching productions (i.e. the name matches, and the time of production is within the start and end times).

To avoid the potential for over-counting, let's say that the end time is not inclusive, but start time is.

Once you have the list of matching productions, you can just use the built-in [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function to get the length of this list. Since you do not need anything other than the length, it's fine to have an arbitrary element value (in this case, `1`).

**Time and Date parsing**

Please see the standard Python docs for this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime

# this is just to make stand-alone code work. Instead, load sample.json into productions as above
productions = json.loads("""[{
    "time": "2021-01-29 09:50:00",
    "production_A": true,
    "production_B": false
  },
  {
    "time": "2021-01-29 10:10:00",
    "production_A": true,
    "production_B": true
  }]""")

def get_counts(prods, shift_start, shift_end):
    def get_datetime(datetime_string):
        return datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    def get_matching_prods(production_name):
        return len([1 for prod in prods if prod[production_name]
                    and shift_start <= get_datetime(prod['time']).time() < shift_end])

    return get_matching_prods('production_A'), get_matching_prods('production_B')

def get_time(time_str):
    return datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M').time()

shifts = {'shiftA': ['6:00', '14:00'], 'shiftB': ['14:00', '20:00']}

for name, shift in shifts.items():
    start, end = shift
    counts = get_counts(productions, get_time(start), get_time(end))
    print(name, shift, counts)
```

Comment: Thank you. If my start and end is in the format `2021-01-28T06:00:00Z` How can I modify `return datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M').time()` so that it would work correctly for all the dates

Comment: `datetime.strptime(time_str,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` -- see link above to docs for explanation